# Cancel sending of text string data with a button click using Application.Current.Properties? WPF C#

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a few buttons that send text string data from a textbox to a textblock on another page. Please see code below.

```
private void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Application.Current.Properties["obj1"] = textbox.Text;
}

private void button2_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Application.Current.Properties["obj2"] = textbox2.Text;
}
```

If i wanted to use a button click to stop/cancel the information being sent, how would I do this?

The page where the text string is received is below

```
protected override void OnInitialized(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnInitialized(e);
        textBlock1.Text = Application.Current.Properties["obj1"]?.ToString();
        textBlock2.Text = Application.Current.Properties["obj2"]?.ToString();
    }
```

Comment: How long is this taking the process?  It doesn't seem like a user would have time to click cancel...

Comment: You can't "stop" the value in the dictionary from being set in any other way than avoid setting the value in the first place. There is no way to cancel a synchronous operation like this once it has been executed.

Comment: You could set the value to string.Empty or null if you want to clear it: Application.Current.Properties["obj2"]  = string.Empty;

Comment: You aren't sending anything in the first place. You are storing some values and you may be accessing them in a different place - noone really knows because you don't show the usage of the properties after setting them. Maybe you should write a little longer explanation what you are actually trying to do

Comment: It's not appropriate to edit your question into a completely different question.  If you have a new question, then ask a new question.

Answer (score 0):

Really you can't stop the send, you can only undo the result. The process of the send is out of reach of your code long before the user has time to react to it, it's a limitation of reaction time. Same way you can't unplug the cat5 to stop an email being sent like the old joke, by the time you reconsider sending, it's long gone and out of your hands.

After all the cancel/stop would take close to as long as the original send, and add the half second of human reaction time...

Your best solution is likely to just set the dictionary value for that key to null, but since we don't see any of your usage this is only a best guess on what will work for you.

Comment: @Rogan you may want to store the previous value somewhere then, that will allow you to set your dictionary back to the previous value of that key. There is no way to actually stop the storage.

Comment: @Rogan This is the solution. You should take your time understanding what is written in it and how you can apply it to your specific case. At least it's the solution given your current development approach. When you start using WPF with MVVM, there might be different options to revert your properties, but that's out of scope here.